# Java graphical library

Tags: java, swing, graph, survey

Within this post I just want to listen to people opinion.

I develop under java and I use to use Java swing to create my graphical interface. I am not a big expert in it but I can usually handle to do what I need. 
However, I believe they are not the best solution since sometimes easy things require quite an effort to be implemented.

I know that there are many other such as AWT (old one) QT, GTK etc., but I never try them (beside a bit of AWT when needed)

I would like to as the community opinion about them. which is the best for you and for which reason? If i should invest some time studying a new one which would you sudgest me?

Comment: Swing is fast and you don't need AWT.

Comment: ok... i'll take it back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a comparison of AWT vs SWT vs SWING 
[AWT vs SWT vs Swing](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/grid/library/os-swingswt/)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which one is better, faster or easier, but I know that I'd gladly spend some time learning GTK or QT 'cause there are GTK and QT libraries not just for Java, but for lot of other languages and I assume that API and gui design principles are pretty similar in every other language, so, if I learn Java GTK, it would be easier for me to learn, for example, PyGTK later, if I need to develop python desktop app.

Comment: A big advantage with Java + Swing over using Qt or GTK with Java is that Swing is better integrated with Java and it makes your application easier to deploy.

Comment: I agree about that. I've made assumption that swing is "the default gui lib" and when one talks about learning some Java gui library, he thinks about learning second Java gui library, after swing.